# SQL case expression in UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, case, oracle-data-integrator

I'm trying to map this particular SQL code for data warehousing purpose.

I have two columns (TARGET) and (NET_SALARY), purpose is to map NET_SALARY with 0 when TARGET is 700, in other cases sub-string net salary 1, 30

I'm receiving missing right parenthesis error

Both columns are varchar2 datatype

```
CASE 
  WHEN SRC_CUSTOMER.TARGET = '700' THEN SRC_CUSTOMER.NET_SALARY = '0'
  ELSE SUBSTR(SRC_CUSTOMER.NET_SALARY,1,30)
END
```

Comment: Is this stored procedure (PLSQL) code, or part of  UPDATE/SELECT? Is it a case _statement_ or a case _expression_?

Comment: @jarlh it is part of an Update/select code

Comment: Then you want a case expression, i.e. do the assignment outside the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is in a context of an ODI mapping/interface, you can only use SQL and not PL/SQL. You can't assign the value to SRC_CUSTOMER.NET_SALARY in the first THEN. You actually only need to set the value you want and it will be mapped to your target attribute.

Try with

```
CASE 
  WHEN SRC_CUSTOMER.TARGET = '700' THEN '0'
  ELSE SUBSTR(SRC_CUSTOMER.NET_SALARY,1,30)
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Move assignment before `case` keyword and put `SRC_CUSTOMER.TARGET` as the inner expression:

```
SRC_CUSTOMER.NET_SALARY = 
CASE SRC_CUSTOMER.TARGET
WHEN '700' THEN '0'
ELSE SUBSTR(SRC_CUSTOMER.NET_SALARY,1,30)
END
```

[image]

[image]

Can be rewritten with [decode function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm):

```
SRC_CUSTOMER.NET_SALARY = decode(SRC_CUSTOMER.TARGET,'700','0',SUBSTR(SRC_CUSTOMER.NET_SALARY,1,30))
```

[image]

Comment: The thing is that SRC_CUSTOMER.TARGET is another column which in this case should be checked for value 700, if found then 0

Comment: @LorikBerisha fixed, updated `SRC_CUSTOMER` to `SRC_CUSTOMER.TARGET`

Comment: That's a case _expression_, not statement.

Comment: @jarlh I wanted to differntiate with inner expression, I updated